# Minimum of Poissons

Tags: poisson-distribution, bounds, extreme-value

Let $X_i\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda_i)$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ and $Y = \min X_i$. Can we show that, for example $\mathbb{E}[Y] \leq f(\lambda,n)\min\lambda_i$ for some $f : (\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{N}) \to [0,1]$ and lower bound the variance $\mathbb{V}[Y]$ by anything meaningful?

Jensen's inequality tells us $$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \mathbb{E}[\min_i X_i] \leq \min_i\mathbb{E}[X_i] = \min_i\lambda_i$$ already but I'd like something more concrete.

Note that [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116308/minimum-of-different-independent-poisson-random-variables) asks a similar question, but is concerned with the entire distribution over $Y$ while I only need bounds on 2 moments. Accordingly, I'd expect a more closed-form answer available.

If it helps, in my case $X_i\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$ and $X_n \sim \text{Pois}(\lambda + \gamma)$ for $\lambda,\gamma>0$ so for $\gamma$ and $n$ large enough we may effectively assume $X_i\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$ are i.i.d (with high probability) for the purposes of estimating $Y$.

Comment: What do you mean by "assume $X_i$" in the last sentence?  Are some words missing?

Comment: @whuber ah thanks. I meant that $X_i$ are effectively i.i.d because for large enough $\gamma$, the probability that $Y = X_n$ is low.

Comment: are you sure you can use Jensen's inequality here?

Comment: @Taylor I’m quite sure: the minimum of a collection of linear functionals over $\mathbb{R}^n$ is concave (draw a picture to check). Denote $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\min X_i = \min \langle X,e_i\rangle$ is a minimum of linear functionals and hence concave, so Jensen applies.

Comment: You do not even need Jensen: $\min X_i\le X_i$ for all $i$'s, hence $\mathbb{E}[\min_i X_i] \leq\mathbb{E}[X_i]$ for all $i$'s.

Comment: @Xi'an nice catch that's definitely cleaner

Answer (score 0):

This only answers half of my question. Lower bounding the variance of $Y$ is still open.

Without loss of generality assume $\lambda_{\min} = \lambda_1\leq \lambda_2\leq \dots \leq \lambda_n = \lambda_{\max}$.
Note that
$$
\mathbb{P}(Y > 0) = \prod_{i=1}^n (1 - e^{-\lambda_i}).
$$
Moreover, $\mathbb{E}[Y | Y>0] \leq \mathbb{E}[X_1 | X_1>0]$.
Bringing these together,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Y] &= \mathbb{E}[Y | Y>0]\mathbb{P}(Y > 0)\\
&\leq \mathbb{E}[X_1 | X_1>0]\mathbb{P}(Y>0)\\
&= \lambda_{\min} \frac{\prod_{i=1}^n(1 - e^{-\lambda_{i}})}{1 - e^{-\lambda_{\min}}}\\
&= \lambda_{\min} \prod_{i=2}^n (1 - e^{-\lambda_i})\tag{$*$}\\
&\leq \lambda_{\min} (1 - e^{-\lambda_{\max}})^{n-1}
\end{align}
as desired. Note that this is sharp for $n=1$, and depending on the situation $(*)$ might be more helpful than the final bound.